# Cannot get char_length() function to work in an Access query

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a database with a lot of words and I am trying to get the last word of certain character length. I have a method for it called getWord() that returns a string for me. For this certain code I am using 5 as the character length that I'm trying to filter. I am no expert in SQL but I tried researching on how to do this and I came across the char_length() function. So i tried using it. However, when I run my program, it does not do anything. Here is my code. BTW, I am using C#.

I would be really grateful for any kind of help. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace take2
{
    class MainGameControl
    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

        public MainGameControl()
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\RJ\c#\take2  - updated\Take2.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
        }

        public string getWord()
        {
            string word = "";
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT Words FROM Dictionary WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(Words) = 5 Order by Words DESC;";
            OleDbDataReader reads = command.ExecuteReader();    

            if (reads.Read())
            {
                word = reads.GetString(0);            
            }
            connection.Close();
            return word;
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or are you using MS-Access, you seem to be asking about one but then state you are using the other. Either way your ORDER BY clause will throw an error since you don't specify the column name you are ordering by.

Comment: `mysql` has a char_length fcn but yeah your `order by` is screwed up

Comment: Oh, sorry. I edited my post and I change my code but still nothing is happening. What I meant to say was I am using MS-Access as a storage for my words like a database. And sql for accessing the words stored in my database. I'm sorry for all the confusion because I'm still new to this environment. I do appreciate any help

Comment: so you don't have a mysql server? Or you do? From your connection string I take it this is a c# / MSAccess question, nothing to do with `mysql`

Comment: Yeah, i dont have any mysql server. Ow. does this  mean that I cant use char_length() function in my command?